# How to show full row highlighting for a ListViewItem?

Tags: .net, winforms

I've got a ListView and, for View = List, would like to have the list items fill up the entire width of the control. That is, when you click an item the whole row is highlighted.

I can't find any setting in the ListView or ListViewItem to control this behavior, and padding with spaces doesn't work very well because I cannot rely on the text being fixed-width.

Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>You can bind the width of the `ListViewItem` to the width of the `ListView` :</strike>

```
...
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" />
        </Style>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
...
```

---

EDIT: you can set the [`ListView.FullRowSelect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.fullrowselect.aspx) property to true

Comment: I imagine that works for WPF, but I'm using Windows Forms! Any idea how that might be done in WinForms?

Comment: oops... I guess I spend to much time coding in WPF, sorry about that. See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Actually, the `FullRowSelect` only works for when View = Details (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.fullrowselect.aspx), but I was able to switch to Details view with no problems, so it worked for me.